# Can not play just on either left or right speaker using python sounddevice

Tags: python

This app is on Windows 10 with headphone plugged in. The stream is mono. Python version 2.7 and sounddevice version 0.3.13

I created a outputStream with 2 channels in blocking mode. When receiving data from upd which I have format the data as followed:

```
   column_stack = np.column_stack((self.zero_array, self.zero_array))
   column_stack[:, 0] = payload[:]
   stacked_data = np.ascontiguousarray(column_stack)
   self.output_stream.write(stacked_data)
```

This still play on both left and right speaker.

thanks